# How to correctly combine my classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning, mlxtend

- I have to solve **2 class classification problem**.
- I have **2 classifiers** that output probabilities. Both of them are neural networks of different architecture. 
  Those 2 classifiers are trained and saved into 2 files.

Now I want to build meta classifier that will take probabilities as input and learn weights of those 2 classifiers. 
So it will automatically decide how much should I "trust" each of my classifiers.

This model is described here: 
http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/classifier/StackingClassifier/#stackingclassifier

I plan to use mlxtend library, but it seems that StackingClassifier refits models. 
I do not want to refit because it takes very huge amount of time. 
From the other side I understand that refitting is necessary to "coordinate" work of each classifier and "tune" the whole system.

What should I do in such situation?

Comment: You could look for a `freeze` or `freeze_weights` parameter. Then you freeze the weights of both neural network, letting only the "combiner" be trained. Alternatively, you can always do it manually by first generating the output of both NNs for all data and then feeding the combiner only with the output of the two NNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't talk about `mlxtend` because I haven't worked with it but I'll tell you the general idea.

You don't have to refit these models to the training set but you have to refit them to parts of it so you can create out-of-fold predictions.

Specifically, split your training data in a few pieces (usually 3 to 10). Keep one piece (i.e. fold) as validation data and train both models on the other folds. Then, predict the probabilities for the validation data using both models. Repeat the procedure treating each fold as a validation set. In the end, you should have the probabilities for all data points in the training set.

Then, you can train a meta-classifier using these probabilities and the ground truth labels. You can use the trained meta-classifier on your new data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your general idea is: take classifiers, fit them, predict with them and save predictions. After that create meta classifier and fit it using predictions from lower level classifiers using cross-validation. Please correct me if I did not got it right. Actually I have thought about it, but could not find the way how to do that using mlxtend. Could you please advise me the tool that is capable for that task?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Although I don't know mlxtend, I'm sure you can do it there. However, you probably have to write your own code to get the cross-validation probabilities. Check also this from scikit-learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html